# Overlay image on right with background colors using :before and :after properties

Tags: html, css

I have a header `div` with a background color with an image on the right. I also have `:before` and `:after` properties on the same `div`.

But after adding those properties, the image is being overshadowed by it.

I tried `overflow:visible !important;` but that does not seem to work.

Any suggestions?

```css
  .header-one {
  font-size: 2rem;
  line-height: 2.5rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.2px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: "Myriad Pro";
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #182561;
  padding: 25px 0px 45px 60px;
  margin-bottom: 0%;
  position: relative;
  img {
    max-width: 100px;
    top: 0;
    right: 20px;
    overflow: visible !important;
    position: absolute;
  }
  .header-one:before {
    content: '';
    border-left: 585px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid #E0E3E1;
    border-right: 585px solid #182561;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
  .header-one:after {
    content: '';
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 585px solid #293FA2;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }
```

```html
HTML:
<h1 class="header-one">
  Heading 1
  <img src="../../assets/img/Group 8.png" alt="" class="pull-right">
</h1>
```

[image: This is what I'm getting.]

Comment: `z-index` is your friend here

Comment: `z-index` will resolve overlapping issue

Comment: `z-index` is your overlapping friend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you want the image to be in front?
Try adding `z-index: 1` to `.header-one` and `z-index: -1` to your pseudo elements. This should work.